# React npm run build - Must use import to load ES Module error

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslintrc

While trying to run a docker build command for a simple React application (built today via create-react-app as I'm learning React), it failed to compile, and the first line of the errors displayed the following: `Must use import to load ES Module`. Below is the complete error.

[image: command line error]

After this, I did 3 things in the `node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/package.json` file:

1. Removed the `"type": "model"` code and tested,
2. Renamed on line 23 `universal.js` to `universal.cjs` and re-added the code removed in step 1,
3. Removed & renamed both.

Here is the file with both changes:
[image]

The error persisted, and there was no difference in the error log. I also tried to use nvm 16 but had no luck.

What is causing this problem, and what is something I can try?

Update 1: screenshot of `package.json` file:
[image]

Update 2: screenshot of projects directory:
[image]

Comment: 1. Never modify node_modules content
2. Could you please share how you import files? - It's essentially saying you're importing files the wrong way, so nothing wrong with the package.json

Comment: @ale917k noted. The only thing I've imported other than the standard create-react-app (CSS, ./App, logo.svg, etc) is TagManager from the react-gtm-module package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from 14/07/2022: the issue was the wrong module version in the Docker file. It was solved shortly after posting this question.

Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIM5irN4Ix0) tutorial, of which the code can be found [here](https://github.com/dgonzo27/react-docker-gcp), I used the following line in the Dockerfile:
`FROM node:12.16.3-alpine as build`

This version was the cause of the error, and was solved using a newer version:
`FROM node:18-alpine as build`

Answer (score 0):

After some further debugging, it appears the cause was due to a mismatch between react and the node version used on Dockerfile (react v18 and react-scripts v5, trying to run on node v12).

To solve, it was required to update the Dockerfile to be based off a more recent node version, e.g.:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

..
```

Comment: It's not listed under dependencies, but under as a separate eslintConfig. I've added an update with a screenshot of the entire file. Should this be removed? Maybe it was added when trying out different solutions, not sure.

Comment: Update: just removed it, but got the same error again.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot - Question at this point is, are you even using eslint? You don't even have it installed as a package. Could you also show a screenshot of your project directories, as well as any file in which you used or imported eslint (if any)?

Comment: Also, to make sure that's not caused by any leftover you got from previous installations you maybe tested out, try with the following at the root of your project: `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json yarn.lock; npm i; npm build`

Comment: I'm not sure what eslint does, and cannot recall installing it. Just uploaded a screenshot of the projects directory.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary. Try with the command from my previous comment, that should then get you sorted :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245432/discussion-between-ale917k-and-nuxurious).

Answer (score 0):

@Nuxurious, I have had same issue like this since last 2 week.
On my local environment both npm run and build were working find as i was using node version 13 or higher.
While on server side on build compile was getting failed. We were using node 12.16.1. I was able to replicate same issue on my local after setting node to 12.16.1. Hope updating node will help you solve this problem.

// Package.json

```
{
  "name": "dbe-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.16.3",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-react-animation": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-buttons": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-common": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-data-tools": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dateinputs": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dialogs": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-form": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-grid": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-inputs": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-intl": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-labels": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-layout": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-listbox": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-notification": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-popup": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-progressbars": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-ripple": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-tooltip": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-treeview": "^5.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^5.5.0",
    "@telerik/kendo-intl": "^2.3.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mobx": "^6.6.0",
    "mobx-react": "^7.5.0",
    "node-gyp-build": "^4.2.3",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-idle-timer": "^4.6.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.10.1",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "websocket": "^1.0.32"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

.ESLINTRC

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true, // Browser global variables like `window` etc.
    "commonjs": true, // CommonJS global variables and CommonJS scoping.Allows require, exports and module.
    "es6": true, // Enable all ECMAScript 6 features except for modules.
    "jest": true, // Jest global variables like `it` etc.
    "node": true // Defines things like process.env when generating through node
  },
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    // "airbnb",
    // "prettier",
    // "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    // "plugin:react-hooks/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest" // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
  },
  "plugins": [
    // "import",
    // "prettier",
    // "react-hooks"
  ],
  // "root": true, // For configuration cascading.
  "rules": {
    "semi": "warn",
    "comma-dangle": "off",
    "quotes": "off",
    // "arrow-parens": "on",
    // "arrow-body-style": "off",
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": "off",
    "operator-linebreak": "off",
    "object-curly-newline": "off",
    "no-unused-expressions": "off",
    // "lines-between-class-members": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "object-shorthand": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "new-cap": "off",
    "prefer-object-spread": "off",
    "prefer-template": "off",
    "prefer-const": "off",
    "linebreak-style": "off",
    "global-require": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": "off",
    "react/destructuring-assignment": "off",
    "react/jsx-fragments": "off",
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      1,
      {
        "extensions": [
          ".js",
          ".jsx"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react/no-access-state-in-setstate": "off",
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn", // Checks effect dependencies
    // kendo ui
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": "off",
    // "prettier/prettier": [
    //   "warn",
    //   {
    //     "semi": true
    //   }
    // ]
  }
}
```

//JSCONFIG

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Hi Alpesh, thanks for the answer but it turned out to be a module using an older version. Solved now, and edited the question to reflect the answer.